# Fourier Series coefficients - How does one separate e^(jwt) from the rest of the answer?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

[How does one go from the first step to the second step? (In red squares in attachment here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk8ln.png)

I don't understand how to separate the complex form or separate the e^(jwt) from the result. Could someone explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$  \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi/6} = \cos(\pi/6) + \mathrm{i}\,\sin(\pi/6) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{\mathrm{i}}{2}  \text{.}  $$
$$  \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\pi/3} = \cos(-\pi/3) + \mathrm{i}\,\sin(-\pi/3) = \frac{-1}{2} + \frac{-\mathrm{i}\sqrt{3}}{2}  \text{.}  $$
(Your source has an error on the sign of the real part.  It's duplicated in the fourth term.)
$$  2 = 2 \text{.}  $$
$$  \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi/3} = \cos(\pi/3) + \mathrm{i}\,\sin(\pi/3) = \frac{-1}{2} + \frac{\mathrm{i}\sqrt{3}}{2}  \text{.}  $$
$$  \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\pi/6} = \cos(-\pi/6) + \mathrm{i}\,\sin(-\pi/6) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{-\mathrm{i}}{2}  \text{.}  $$

These are all specializations of [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula),
$$  \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} = \cos(\theta) +\mathrm{i} \,\sin(\theta)  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick and clear answer!